# ESP-01s LED inverted behavior

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm seeing a strange anomaly with my ESP-01s.  When I use the function "digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH)" the LED turns off, and when I use the function "digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW)" the LED turns on.  Of course the LED pin is initialized using "pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT)" in the setup section.  I verified this behavior by modifying the Blink example (HIGH for 2 seconds, LOW for 1 second).  Previously, the LED behaved normally, and I'm not sure at what point while running test programs it's behavior inverted.  I've read through the datasheet, but could find nothing.  Is there some setting I'm missing that enables this behavior?

Comment: The built-in LED on the ESP-01s is wired between the positive power supply and a GPIO pin, so setting that pin LOW is how you turn it on.  This *is* "behaving normally".

Comment: @jasonharper, thanks.  I must have missed that in my previous tests.